# Detect if the app has been cracked/pirated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, piracy

I'm making an app that has purchases from the playstore, but there are always people who modify the app to be able to crack the app and buy the products for free using luckt patcher or another app. And I want to make a system in case the app signature is not the original app refuses to open, but I don't know where to start, can someone help me?

Comment: Obfuscation is the solution, you can google about it

Comment: Obfuscation is definitely *NOT* the solution. I know a few very popular apps which *do not* obfuscate their code, since they consider it a waste of time, and a source of frustration (it often is).

Answer (score 2):

I hate to be a cynic, but this is fundamentally an arms race type problem. Every measure you put in can be defeated. Piracy will fundamentally affect you two ways:  Loss of revenue and higher expenses. The more complex you make your anti-piracy measures, the greater the cost (in terms of time and money). You do not want to make your anti-piracy measures more expensive than the likely loss of revenue due to piracy.

Do you have an app generating revenue? If so, what is your estimated loss of revenue due to piracy?  If I was starting with a new app, I would seriously consider putting no or little anti-piracy measures because the cost is not worth it in the early stages.

That said, checkout https://github.com/javiersantos/PiracyChecker